# Sharing to Facebook with ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

I have been trying to share some images to facebook using the `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE Intent`.

The code that i wrote for this is.

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    for (DeviceImage image : catchImagesURI) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onClickShareFB: image uri " + image.getImageURI());
        imageUris.add(image.getImageURI());
    }
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
}
```

where the Uri of the images are `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshot_1497529599.png` and `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/calendar.png`

When i choose Facebook from the options i get

[image]

Is there something wrong with the format of the Image Uri or am i doing this completely wrong?

Comment: have you added permission to read & write external storage

Comment: Thats what i thought was wrong too but when i added the permission nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something wrong with the format of the Image Uri

They are not valid `Uri` values. A `Uri` has a scheme. For example, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152988/sharing-to-facebook-with-action-send-multiple` is a `Uri` with a scheme of `https`. Given the paths that you are using, presumably the scheme should be `file`.

Whether Facebook can use `file` `Uri` values pointing to external storage is a separate matter. Probably it can.